# Threading in Tkinter with Button Command

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm building a tkinter app and as a part of it the user has to upload a file, write a message and then press a `Button` whose command runs in another thread.

```
self.sidebar_button = Button(self.sidebar_frame, text="send your message", 
                                                        command=threading.Thread(target=send_msg).start)
```

If the `Button` is pressed in the right condition then everything is fine.
However, if the user doesn't upload the file and write the message before pressing the `Button` then i show the user an error message. The problem here is that since the first `Button` press has started the thread, it can't start again.
Can you think of a workaround for this problem?
Is it possible to disable the `Button` before the right conditions are met?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# This is called each time there is a change in the entry
def check_conditions(*args):
    message_text = message_var.get()
    # Here we check the conditions:
    if message_text == "":
        button.config(state="disabled")
    else:
        button.config(state="normal")

def send():
    message_text = message_var.get()
    print(f"Send: {message_text!r}")

root = tk.Tk()

message_var = tk.StringVar(root)
# When the value of the `message_var` has changed, call `check_conditions`
message_var.trace("w", check_conditions)

# Create the entry and attach `message_var`
message = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=message_var)
message.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Send", command=send, state="disabled")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It uses `<tk.StringVar>.trace("w", <function>)` to call `check_conditions` each time the user changes the entry. For more info, read [this](https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-StringVar.php).

`tkinter` doesn't always like being called from other threads, so avoid using `threading` when using `tkinter`.

Comment: The command function is causing tkinter to freeze even though the code is running. From everything I've read it seems like my only choice is to use a separate thread to run the function.

Comment: What are you doing in that function that takes so long that the GUI freezes? You can put that in another thread. Be careful because if you call `tkinter` from the other thread, it can crash python.

Comment: It's part of a browser automation task I'm running so it takes a while to finish. I'm not sure i understand what you mean. Could you send me any documents that refer to this? I'd love to learn more about it.